# How to use Joomla for insert, delete, display and update data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla-4

I'm just started to learn using Joomla and one of the things that I need to do is to build a form that can insert data and that data can be displayed to another Joomla page.

I got a few comments from a Facebook user who said that most Joomlers are using an extension to insert data. If I'm using an extension, how can I display the data that has been saved to other tables in my webpage?

Also, if I don't want to use an extension, how can I build a form on my own?

Answer (score 1):

To build something without the use of extensions, you'll need to develop a component.

You could build a your own component with a form that saves input into the database, and a part that displays it on the website. For that I'd advice to look at Joomla's core components, how they are build and work.

I would **use a good IDE** (like PHPStorm, Visual Studio, Netbeans) in combination **with Xdebug** that enables you to step through Joomla's code to see what's happening and the contents of all variables.

Furthermore there's some documentation for developers available. See the **For Developers** part, and under "Appendices" the **Joomla 4.x Extensions - Simple working examples explained** at https://docs.joomla.org/JDOC:Joomla_4_Tutorials_Project